# receive data from a listener which is inside a Service

Tags: android, service, listener

i am looking for a fast way to get the data from the listeners, which are in my service, to an activity.

I tried it with variables where i store the current value and read it in the activity, but this is to slow!

I start my service from an activity. I read that it's possible to start a service independently of an activity and bound from an activity to this service too. Could this be a slution? How would it look like?

Here is a part of my service:

public class DataService extends Service {

```
private VehicleManager mVehicleManager;

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, VehicleManager.class);
    bindService(intent1, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    startThreadUpdatingDatabase();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        mVehicleManager = ((VehicleBinder) service).getService();

        mVehicleManager.addListener(EngineSpeed.class, engineSpeedListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

EngineSpeed.Listener engineSpeedListener = new EngineSpeed.Listener() {
    public void receive(Measurement measurement) {

        final EngineSpeed data = (EngineSpeed) measurement;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Double engineSpeedValue = data.getValue().doubleValue();//i want this value using in an activity!!
            }
        }).start();

    }
};
```

}

Comment: use "bound local service" pattern http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best way to do it, but try this one :

Add an update(double value) method in your activity.
Pass the context to your service when starting it and add this after :

```
Double engineSpeedValue = data.getValue().doubleValue(); // I want this value used in an activity!!
(YourAcitvityName) context).update(engineSpeedValue);
```